# JavaFX randomly fill ListViews

Tags: javafx

I was trying to make a program where you can add names as CheckBoxes. By checking them and pressing the randomize button all the names would be placed in 2 different ListViews (each name can be placed only once and each ListView has to have the same number of names or 1 more name inside). I have no idea how it should be written in the "onRandom" section.

```
package sample;


import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import java.util.Objects;


public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private Button add;
    @FXML
    private Button delete;
    @FXML
    private VBox vbox;
    @FXML
    private TextField text;
    @FXML
    private Button random;
    @FXML
    private ListView listview1;
    @FXML
    private ListView listview2;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox cb;




    @FXML
    void initialize() {

    }

    @FXML
    public void onEnter(ActionEvent e){
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(text.getText());
        vbox.getChildren().add(cb);
        if (text.getText().matches("")) {
            vbox.getChildren().remove(cb);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void onAdd(ActionEvent e) {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(text.getText());
        vbox.getChildren().add(cb);
        if (text.getText().matches("")) {
            vbox.getChildren().remove(cb);
        }
    }
    @FXML
    public void onDelete(ActionEvent e) {
        vbox.getChildren().removeIf(child -> ((CheckBox) child).isSelected());
    }

    @FXML
    public void onRandom(ActionEvent e) {
        vbox.getChildren()
                .stream()
                .map(item -> (CheckBox) item)
                .filter(item -> item.isSelected())
                .filter(value -> Objects.nonNull(value))
                .forEach(value -> {
                    listview1.getItems().add(value.getText());
                    listview2.getItems().add(value.getText());
                });
        }
}
```

This one below is just for testing.

```
.forEach(value -> {
                    listview1.getItems().add(value.getText());
                    listview2.getItems().add(value.getText());
                });
```

Here is my FXML file https://pastebin.com/9v8e0c0Y

Comment: What do you mean by *each name can be placed only once* ?  You mean list-view shouldn't hold the duplicate name? *or 1 more name inside* ? can you give an example to illustrate your requirement?

Comment: Yes, ListView can not hold duplicates. Here is an example: https://imgur.com/a/dFKq2YR

Comment: Ok, is there any-condition on which text-value should be put into your list-views. I mean in your example I can see 2/2 different texts are for listview1 and listview2 - do you mean by you're trying to put *randomly* ?

Comment: It should work like this: Put names (checked) randomly into 2 different ListViews. It should work like every time you press the button each ListView stores different names.

Comment: [mcve] please .. _here_ not on any external site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Collections.shuffle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) to create a random permutation of the list, then add the first half to one `ListView` and the rest to the other.

```
// do not use raw types
@FXML
private ListView<String> listview1;
@FXML
private ListView<String> listview2;
...

private final Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
```

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<>(); // copy children to new list

// the following loop imho is easier to comprehend than the Stream implementation
for (Node child : vbox.getChildren()) {
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) child;
    if (cb.isSelected) {
        items.add(cb.getText());
    }
}

Collections.shuffle(items, randomNumberGenerator);
final int size = items.size();
final int half = size / 2;

// add first half to first ListView and second half to second ListView
listview1.getItems().setAll(items.sublist(0, half));
listview2.getItems().setAll(items.sublist(half, size));
```

---

Note that some of the method calls on `Stream` are actually unnecessary in your case:

```
.filter(value -> Objects.nonNull(value))
```

Checking for `null` is never necessary for the `children` list of a `Parent`. The list implementation prevents `null` from being inserted to that list. The previous filter whould have thrown a NPE in cases where that predicate yields `false` anyways. In cases where you do need a predicate like this, you can use a method reference to shorten the code:

```
.filter(Objects::nonNull)
```